# Can the sign of non-relativistic potentials be determined from QFT amplitudes?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, potential, scattering, born-oppenheimer-approximation

In many QFT books and courses people use a non-relativistic approximation to extract potentials from QFT. They do so by comparing the scattering in QFT with the scattering in Quantum Mechanics, in the Born approximation. This is done in Peskin & Schroeder's book, also in Schwartz. Here is an example available online (from a course in Cornell):

[https://www.classe.cornell.edu/~yuvalg/p4444/hw8-sol.pdf](https://www.classe.cornell.edu/%7Eyuvalg/p4444/hw8-sol.pdf)

What I don't understand is: how can they uniquely determine the sign of the potential in all these calculations?

This is essential to say if the interaction is attractive or repulsive. They all relate the sign of the potential to the QFT scattering amplitude, but the sign of the amplitude itself should have no physical significance (amplitudes in QFT should be determined up to a complex phase, right?)

My feeling is that you actually need to know beforehand if some potential is attractive or repulsive. Once we use one potential to set our convention, then we could use it to determine the signs of other potentials (e.g. once we know the sign of the Yukawa potential we could predict the sign of the Coulomb potential, in relation to the Yukawa sign).

ps: this question is related to this one: "https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/389461/is-the-sign-of-an-amplitude-in-qft-meaningful", but I'm asking it in a way that will force people to answer the main point, which was avoided in that case.